Get text from nested DIV by contents of parent div
I am trying to extract some text from a webpage.  I've tried something like:
var headings = document.evaluate("//div[contains(., 'Location')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

but it returns the whole containing div.  I just want to extract the text "Town Center".  So basically, the smallest element containing that text.
Here's an edited and shortened model of the webpage.
<!-- ****************** CONTENT STARTS ****************** -->
<div class="container-fluid px-1">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 sidebar-offcanvas leftnav-row-padding" id="grantFamily">
        </div>            
     
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
            <div class="col-sm-10"><h1 role="heading"><span class="fa fa-folder-open text-gf" aria-hidden="true"></span>Title</h1></div>
        </div> 

<div class="card mb-3" id="grant-title-panel">
  <div class="card-header bg-primary text-white">
    <div class="row vertical-align-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a class="text-white fw-bold" href="xxx" title="Snapshot" target="_blank"><u>XXXXXX</u></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-end">         
                    <span>Appl ID: 12345</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <strong>Name</strong>
                    <div>Doe, John
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <strong> Title</strong><div>Blah Blah</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <strong>Status</strong> <div>Ready<br/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <strong>Location</strong> <span class="text-uppercase"><div>Town Center</div></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="row mb-2 gf-grey-bg">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-2">
                        <strong>Checklist</strong>
                            <div>Not Started</div>
                        </div>
            </div>
   </div>
 </div>


Is there a reason you're trying to use XPath instead of DOM traversal?

No, I'm open to any approach.

Does the HTML that you're trying to scrape data from always follow the same structure?

Should it find a single element or could there be multiple elements?

You know what, I'm making this too complicated.  As Rory McCrossan pointed out, the order of the fields doesn't change.  I can use a JS selector such as "document.querySelector("#grant-title-panel > div.card-body > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span > div")"

Yep, exactly :)
